# Sitecore broken links reports - how to find wrong component

Tags: presentation, broken-links

I have a message about a broken link at final layout at some page item on my Sitecore 8.2 instance.

I ran a `Scan for broken link report` and find a record about this page item. The report shows an item Id with error, at final renderings.

I open raw value at final rendering field for this item and can't find any links to those wrong ID.
I don't have a lot of components on my page and page looks ok in Experience Editor mode.

No components link to those missed item.

I rebuilt the link database, but the error is still present. Usually, I ignore such errors but in this case, I need to know why I see it.

Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: Can you please check if the datasource for each renderings are still present in your content tree?
Maybe one rendering is referencing one item which has been deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ID is not stored in the Final Renderings field on the page item, it may be inherited from standard values and simply not stored on that item because of support for layout deltas.

## If you're curious where it's stored

Check the raw values of the Final Renderings field of the `__Standard Values` of your template (and any other base templates that may define presentation details). It may be defined there.

## If you just want to fix it

Try simply opening the presentation details for the offending item and clicking OK. That often clears out any renderings that it can't find.

Comment: it was strange rendering properties